# ".Text" property not defined?

Tags: vb6, infragistics

I have tried activating multiple resources, but whatever I do, the .Text method is not defined / recognized, the .Text is in the following line of code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  StartDate = Date

  meBakBlauw.Text = "-"
  meBakGeel.Text = "-"
```

The prompt that comes up after running it says: 'Method or Datamember is not found'.
Is there somebody that knows how to fix this?
It's written by our old programmer where he build in a restricting on resources that expanded. It's written in Visual Basic 6.

The full program:

```
VERSION 5.00
Begin VB.Form frmKoppelBak
   BackColor       =   &H80000005&
   Caption         =   "Bakken Koppelen"
   ClientHeight    =   9285
   ClientLeft      =   60
   ClientTop       =   750
   ClientWidth     =   13590
   LinkTopic       =   "Form1"
   MaxButton       =   0   'False
   ScaleHeight     =   9285
   ScaleWidth      =   13590
   Begin VB.PictureBox meBakGeel
      BackColor       =   &H0000FFFF&
      Enabled         =   0   'False
      BeginProperty Font
         Name            =   "Arial Black"
         Size            =   72
         Charset         =   0
         Weight          =   900
         Underline       =   0   'False
         Italic          =   0   'False
         Strikethrough   =   0   'False
      EndProperty
      ForeColor       =   &H00000000&
      Height          =   1440
      Left            =   7080
      ScaleHeight     =   1380
      ScaleWidth      =   5940
      TabIndex        =   6
      TabStop         =   0   'False
      Top             =   2280
      Width           =   6000
   End
   Begin VB.PictureBox meBakBlauw
      BackColor       =   &H00FF0000&
      Enabled         =   0   'False
      BeginProperty Font
         Name            =   "Arial Black"
         Size            =   72
         Charset         =   0
         Weight          =   900
         Underline       =   0   'False
         Italic          =   0   'False
         Strikethrough   =   0   'False
      EndProperty
      ForeColor       =   &H00FFFFFF&
      Height          =   1440
      Left            =   7080
      ScaleHeight     =   1380
      ScaleWidth      =   5940
      TabIndex        =   5
      TabStop         =   0   'False
      Top             =   600
      Width           =   6000
   End
   Begin VB.PictureBox meBlauw
      Appearance      =   0  'Flat
      Enabled         =   0   'False
      BeginProperty Font
         Name            =   "Arial Black"
         Size            =   72
         Charset         =   0
         Weight          =   900
         Underline       =   0   'False
         Italic          =   0   'False
         Strikethrough   =   0   'False
      EndProperty
      ForeColor       =   &H80000008&
      Height          =   1455
      Index           =   0
      Left            =   480
      ScaleHeight     =   1425
      ScaleWidth      =   6345
      TabIndex        =   4
      TabStop         =   0   'False
      Top             =   600
      Width           =   6375
   End
   Begin VB.PictureBox PVMaskEdit4
      Appearance      =   0  'Flat
      Enabled         =   0   'False
      BeginProperty Font
         Name            =   "Arial Black"
         Size            =   48
         Charset         =   0
         Weight          =   900
         Underline       =   0   'False
         Italic          =   0   'False
         Strikethrough   =   0   'False
      EndProperty
      ForeColor       =   &H80000008&
      Height          =   1455
      Left            =   495
      ScaleHeight     =   1425
      ScaleWidth      =   6345
      TabIndex        =   3
      TabStop         =   0   'False
      Top             =   7200
      Width           =   6375
   End
   Begin VB.PictureBox PVMaskEdit3
      Appearance      =   0  'Flat
      BackColor       =   &H80000014&
      Enabled         =   0   'False
      BeginProperty Font
         Name            =   "Arial Black"
         Size            =   48
         Charset         =   0
         Weight          =   900
         Underline       =   0   'False
         Italic          =   0   'False
         Strikethrough   =   0   'False
      EndProperty
      ForeColor       =   &H80000008&
      Height          =   1455
      Left            =   480
      ScaleHeight     =   1425
      ScaleWidth      =   6345
      TabIndex        =   2
      TabStop         =   0   'False
      Top             =   5520
      Width           =   6375
   End
   Begin VB.PictureBox meScanOrder
      CausesValidation=   0   'False
      BeginProperty Font
         Name            =   "Arial Black"
         Size            =   48
         Charset         =   0
         Weight          =   900
         Underline       =   0   'False
         Italic          =   0   'False
         Strikethrough   =   0   'False
      EndProperty
      ForeColor       =   &H80000008&
      Height          =   1440
      Left            =   7080
      ScaleHeight     =   1380
      ScaleWidth      =   5940
      TabIndex        =   0
      Top             =   5520
      Width           =   6000
   End
   Begin VB.PictureBox meScanBak
      BackColor       =   &H0000FFFF&
      CausesValidation=   0   'False
      BeginProperty Font
         Name            =   "Arial Black"
         Size            =   48
         Charset         =   0
         Weight          =   900
         Underline       =   0   'False
         Italic          =   0   'False
         Strikethrough   =   0   'False
      EndProperty
      ForeColor       =   &H00000000&
      Height          =   1440
      Left            =   7080
      ScaleHeight     =   1380
      ScaleWidth      =   5940
      TabIndex        =   1
      Top             =   7200
      Width           =   6000
   End
   Begin VB.PictureBox meBlauw
      Appearance      =   0  'Flat
      Enabled         =   0   'False
      BeginProperty Font
         Name            =   "Arial Black"
         Size            =   72
         Charset         =   0
         Weight          =   900
         Underline       =   0   'False
         Italic          =   0   'False
         Strikethrough   =   0   'False
      EndProperty
      ForeColor       =   &H80000008&
      Height          =   1455
      Index           =   1
      Left            =   480
      ScaleHeight     =   1425
      ScaleWidth      =   6345
      TabIndex        =   7
      TabStop         =   0   'False
      Top             =   2280
      Width           =   6375
   End
   Begin VB.Timer Timer1
      Enabled         =   0   'False
      Interval        =   10000
      Left            =   255
      Top             =   75
   End
   Begin VB.Frame Frame1
      BackColor       =   &H80000005&
      Caption         =   "Koppel Order aan Bak"
      Height          =   4095
      Left            =   120
      TabIndex        =   8
      Top             =   4920
      Width           =   13320
   End
   Begin VB.Menu File
      Caption         =   "&File"
      Begin VB.Menu mnuExit
         Caption         =   "&Exit"
      End
   End
End
Attribute VB_Name = "frmKoppelBak"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Const SND_SYNC = &H0
Const SND_ASYNC = &H1
Const SND_NODEFAULT = &H2
Const SND_LOOP = &H8
Const SND_NOSTOP = &H10

Const glBlauweBak As Long = 1
Const glGeleBak As Long = 2
Const glNeeGELEBak As Long = 3
Const glOrderOnbekend As Long = 4
Const glNietVoorLegborden As Long = 5
Const glOngeldigBakNummer As Long = 6

Dim INIfile As String
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim ConnectOK As Boolean
Dim ChildHDL As Variant
Dim GeleBak As Boolean

Dim pp5000 As ADODB.Connection
Dim KoppelBak As ADODB.Command
Dim BakkenPerKleur As ADODB.Command
Dim PakOrder As ADODB.Command

Dim ConnStrPP5000 As String
Dim winTop As Integer
Dim winLeft As Integer
Dim winHeight As Integer
Dim winWidth As Integer

Dim wavBlauweBak         As String
Dim wavGeleBak           As String
Dim wavNeeGELEBak        As String
Dim wavNietVoorLegborden As String
Dim wavOrderOnbekend     As String
Dim wavOngeldigBakNummer As String

Private Declare Function GetPrivateProfileString _
  Lib "kernel32" _
  Alias "GetPrivateProfileStringA" ( _
    ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
    ByVal lpKeyName As Any, _
    ByVal lpDefault As String, _
    ByVal lpReturnedString As String, _
    ByVal nSize As Long, _
    ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function WritePrivateProfileString _
  Lib "kernel32" _
  Alias "WritePrivateProfileStringA" ( _
    ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
    ByVal lpKeyName As Any, _
    ByVal lpString As Any, _
    ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function sndPlaySound _
  Lib "winmm.dll" _
  Alias "sndPlaySoundA" ( _
    ByVal lpszSoundName As String, _
    ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long

Private Sub Form_Load()
  StartDate = Date

  meBakBlauw.Text = "-"
  meBakGeel.Text = "-"

  INIfile = App.Path & "\KoppelBak.ini"
  GetSettings

  ConnectOK = False

  connectDB

  If Not ConnectOK Then
    MsgBox "ERROR: Geen verbinding met de database", vbCritical, "Koppel Bak"
    Unload Me
    End
  End If

  Me.Top = winTop
  Me.Left = winLeft

  TelBakken
  Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
  If (frmKoppelBak.WindowState <> vbMinimized) Then
    If (frmKoppelBak.Width <> 13710) Then
      frmKoppelBak.Width = 13710
    End If
    If (frmKoppelBak.Height <> 10095) Then
      frmKoppelBak.Height = 10095
    End If
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
  Dim INIresult As Long

  disconnectDB
  If (frmKoppelBak.WindowState <> vbMinimized) Then
    INIresult = WritePrivateProfileString("Settings", "winTop", CStr(Me.Top), INIfile)
    INIresult = WritePrivateProfileString("Settings", "winLeft", CStr(Me.Left), INIfile)
  End If
End Sub

Sub Geluidje(GeluidNR As Long)
  Dim SoundName As String
  Dim wFlags, playRes As Long

  wFlags = SND_ASYNC Or SND_NODEFAULT
  SoundName = ""

  Select Case GeluidNR
    Case glBlauweBak
      SoundName = wavBlauweBak
    Case glGeleBak
      SoundName = wavGeleBak
    Case glNeeGELEBak
      SoundName = wavNeeGELEBak
    Case glOrderOnbekend
      SoundName = wavOrderOnbekend
    Case glNietVoorLegborden
      SoundName = wavNietVoorLegborden
    Case glOngeldigBakNummer
      SoundName = wavOngeldigBakNummer
    Case Else
      SoundName = "Windows XP Hardwarefout.wav"
  End Select

  If (SoundName <> "") Then
    playRes = sndPlaySound(SoundName, wFlags)
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub mnuExit_Click()
  Unload frmKoppelBak
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
  Dim INIresult As Long

  Timer1.Enabled = False

  If (Timer > 18000) Then '05:00
    If Not ConnectOK Then
      connectDB
    End If
    TelBakken
  Else
    If ConnectOK Then
      disconnectDB
    End If
    If (StartDate < Date) Then 'nieuwe instance starten en zelf stoppen i.v.m memory leaks
      If (frmKoppelBak.WindowState <> vbMinimized) Then
        INIresult = WritePrivateProfileString("Settings", "winTop", CStr(Me.Top), INIfile)
        INIresult = WritePrivateProfileString("Settings", "winLeft", CStr(Me.Left), INIfile)
      End If

      ChildHDL = Shell(App.Path & "\" & App.EXEName, vbNormalNoFocus)
      If ChildHDL <> 0 Then
        Unload frmKoppelBak
        End
      End If
    End If
  End If

  Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub TelBakken()
  meBakBlauw.Text = "-"
  meBakGeel.Text = "-"
  BakkenPerKleur.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
  meBakBlauw.Text = CStr(BakkenPerKleur.Parameters("@o_BlauweBakken").Value)
  meBakGeel.Text = CStr(BakkenPerKleur.Parameters("@o_GeleBakken").Value)
End Sub

Private Sub meScanOrder_GotFocusEvent()
  meScanOrder.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub meScanOrder_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
  Dim FoutCode As Long

  If KeyAscii = 13 Then
    ' Zoek de order en bepaal de bakkleur

    meScanBak.Text = ""
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    PakOrder.Parameters("@i_AUFTRAG").Value = meScanOrder.Text
    PakOrder.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
    Timer1.Enabled = True

    FoutCode = PakOrder.Parameters("@o_FoutCode").Value
    GeleBak = PakOrder.Parameters("@o_GeleBak").Value

    'MsgBox CStr(FoutCode) & "; " & CStr(GeleBak)

    If (FoutCode = 0) Then
      If GeleBak Then
        meScanBak.ForeColor = &H0&
        meScanBak.BackColor = &HFFFF&
        Call Geluidje(glGeleBak)
      Else
        meScanBak.ForeColor = &HFFFFFF
        meScanBak.BackColor = &HFF0000
        Call Geluidje(glBlauweBak)
      End If

      ' Nu naar het baknummer

      meScanBak.SetFocus
    Else
      If (FoutCode = 1) Then
        Call Geluidje(glOrderOnbekend)
      Else
        Call Geluidje(glNietVoorLegborden)
      End If
      meScanOrder.Text = ""
      meScanOrder.SetFocus
    End If
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub meScanBak_GotFocusEvent()
  meScanBak.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub meScanBak_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
  Dim sBakNR As String
  Dim iBakNR As Long

  If KeyAscii = 13 Then
    sBakNR = meScanBak.Text
    If (Len(sBakNR) = 4) And IsNumeric(sBakNR) Then
      iBakNR = CLng(sBakNR)
      If GeleBak And (iBakNR > 1049) Then
        Geluidje (glNeeGELEBak)
        meScanBak.Text = ""
        meScanBak.SetFocus
      ElseIf (iBakNR < 1000) Or (iBakNR > 1450) Then
        Geluidje (glOngeldigBakNummer)
        meScanBak.Text = ""
        meScanBak.SetFocus
      Else
        'pp5000.BeginTrans

        Timer1.Enabled = False
        With KoppelBak
          .Parameters("rVal").Value = 0
          .Parameters("@terminal_id").Value = ""
          .Parameters("@i_Ordernr").Value = meScanOrder.Text
          .Parameters("@i_HuidigeBak").Value = ""
          .Parameters("@i_NieuweBak").Value = sBakNR
          .Parameters("@i_HuidigeZone").Value = ""

          .Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
        End With

        'pp5000.CommitTrans

        TelBakken
        Timer1.Enabled = True
        meScanBak.Text = ""
        meScanOrder.Text = ""
        meScanOrder.SetFocus
      End If
    End If
  End If
End Sub

Sub connectDB()
  Dim iloop As Integer

  On Error GoTo CheckConnectError

  If (pp5000 Is Nothing) Then
    Set pp5000 = New ADODB.Connection
  ElseIf (pp5000.State <> adStateClosed) Then
    pp5000.Close
  End If
  pp5000.ConnectionString = ConnStrPP5000
  'pp5000.Properties("Multiple Connections") = True
  'pp5000.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Native Client};Server=LT-KTS\SQLEXPRESS;Database=PP5000-v36;Uid=eks;Pwd=kardex."
  pp5000.Open

  Set KoppelBak = New ADODB.Command

  With KoppelBak
    .ActiveConnection = pp5000
    .CommandText = "EKS_Koppel_Bak"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .NamedParameters = False
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("rVal", adInteger, adParamReturnValue, 8, 0)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@terminal_id", adVarChar, adParamInput, 24, "")
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@i_Ordernr", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, "")
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@i_HuidigeBak", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, "")
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@i_NieuweBak", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, "")
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@i_HuidigeZone", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, "")

  End With

  Set BakkenPerKleur = New ADODB.Command

  With BakkenPerKleur
    .ActiveConnection = pp5000
    .CommandText = "EKS_BakkenPerKleur"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .NamedParameters = True
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@o_BlauweBakken", adInteger, adParamOutput)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@o_GeleBakken", adInteger, adParamOutput)
  End With

  Set PakOrder = New ADODB.Command

  With PakOrder
    .ActiveConnection = pp5000
    .CommandText = "EKS_PakOrder"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .NamedParameters = True
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@i_AUFTRAG", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, "")
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@o_FoutCode", adInteger, adParamOutput)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@o_GeleBak", adBoolean, adParamOutput)
  End With

  ConnectOK = True
  Exit Sub

CheckConnectError:
  If Not (pp5000 Is Nothing) Then
    If (pp5000.Errors.Count > 0) Then
      For iloop = 1 To pp5000.Errors.Count
        MsgBox "ERROR:" & vbCrLf & _
          "Description = " & pp5000.Errors.Item(iloop - 1).Description & vbCrLf & _
          "NativeError = " & CStr(pp5000.Errors.Item(iloop - 1).NativeError) & vbCrLf & _
          "Number = " & CStr(pp5000.Errors.Item(iloop - 1).Number) & vbCrLf & _
          "Source = " & pp5000.Errors.Item(iloop - 1).Source & vbCrLf & _
          "SQLState = " & pp5000.Errors.Item(iloop - 1).SQLState, vbCritical, "PP database"
      Next iloop
    End If
  End If
End Sub

Sub disconnectDB()
  If Not (pp5000 Is Nothing) Then
    If Not (KoppelBak Is Nothing) Then
      Set KoppelBak.ActiveConnection = Nothing
      Set KoppelBak = Nothing
    End If

    If Not (BakkenPerKleur Is Nothing) Then
      Set BakkenPerKleur.ActiveConnection = Nothing
      Set BakkenPerKleur = Nothing
    End If

    If (pp5000.State = adStateOpen) Then
      pp5000.Close
    End If
    Set pp5000 = Nothing
  End If

  ConnectOK = False
End Sub

Public Sub GetSettings()
  Dim INIresult As Long
  Dim INIvalue As String

  INIvalue = String(255, vbNullChar)
  INIresult = GetPrivateProfileString("Settings", "winTop", "0", INIvalue, 255, INIfile)
  If (INIresult > 0) Then
    winTop = CInt(Left(INIvalue, INIresult))
  End If

  INIvalue = String(255, vbNullChar)
  INIresult = GetPrivateProfileString("Settings", "winLeft", "0", INIvalue, 255, INIfile)
  If (INIresult > 0) Then
    winLeft = CInt(Left(INIvalue, INIresult))
  End If

'  INIvalue = String(255, vbNullChar)
'  INIresult = GetPrivateProfileString("Settings", "winHeight", "3600", INIvalue, 255, INIfile)
'  If (INIresult > 0) Then
'    winHeight = CInt(Left(INIvalue, INIresult))
'  End If
'
'  INIvalue = String(255, vbNullChar)
'  INIresult = GetPrivateProfileString("Settings", "winWidth", "4680", INIvalue, 255, INIfile)
'  If (INIresult > 0) Then
'    winWidth = CInt(Left(INIvalue, INIresult))
'  End If


  INIvalue = String(255, vbNullChar)
  INIresult = GetPrivateProfileString("Connection", "ConnStrPP5000", "Driver={SQL Native Client};Server=schuurkx\sqlexpress;Database=PP5000-v36;Uid=eks;Pwd=kardex.", INIvalue, 255, INIfile)
  If (INIresult > 0) Then
    ConnStrPP5000 = Left(INIvalue, INIresult)
  End If

  INIvalue = String(255, vbNullChar)
  INIresult = GetPrivateProfileString("Geluiden", "BlauweBak", "", INIvalue, 255, INIfile)
  If (INIresult > 0) Then
    wavBlauweBak = Left(INIvalue, INIresult)
  End If

  INIvalue = String(255, vbNullChar)
  INIresult = GetPrivateProfileString("Geluiden", "GeleBak", "", INIvalue, 255, INIfile)
  If (INIresult > 0) Then
    wavGeleBak = Left(INIvalue, INIresult)
  End If

  INIvalue = String(255, vbNullChar)
  INIresult = GetPrivateProfileString("Geluiden", "NeeGELEBak", "", INIvalue, 255, INIfile)
  If (INIresult > 0) Then
    wavNeeGELEBak = Left(INIvalue, INIresult)
  End If

  INIvalue = String(255, vbNullChar)
  INIresult = GetPrivateProfileString("Geluiden", "OrderOnbekend", "", INIvalue, 255, INIfile)
  If (INIresult > 0) Then
    wavOrderOnbekend = Left(INIvalue, INIresult)
  End If

  INIvalue = String(255, vbNullChar)
  INIresult = GetPrivateProfileString("Geluiden", "NietVoorLegborden", "", INIvalue, 255, INIfile)
  If (INIresult > 0) Then
    wavNietVoorLegborden = Left(INIvalue, INIresult)
  End If

  INIvalue = String(255, vbNullChar)
  INIresult = GetPrivateProfileString("Geluiden", "OngeldigBakNummer", "", INIvalue, 255, INIfile)
  If (INIresult > 0) Then
    wavOngeldigBakNummer = Left(INIvalue, INIresult)
  End If
End Sub
```

I hope this gives some more clarification to what it is and does?

Comment: This line looks very suspect. `BakkenPerKleur.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please use the correct tag for your question. Tags are used to categorize questions and to attract to your question experts on the matter, Using an incorrect tag can only upset the people looking at your question expecting something they know and finding something else.

Comment: Whe ever we try to run the code, the only error that comes up is that the .Text gets marked and a prompt says: Method not defined

Comment: That depends on what type `meBakBlauw` and `meBakGeel` are, doesn't it?

Comment: Are you writing your code in Visual Studio 2006? The Visual Basic that comes with Visual Studio 2006 is most assuredly vb.net.

Comment: I will upload a larger part of the code!

Comment: @Mary Oke, I will update the tag to vb.net as well? problem is that the developer for this program passed away unfortunatly but did not document anything, and we are very dependent on this program, I will upload a bigger part of the code

Comment: When you are in design view, can you check the name and type of the Text Box controls. Do you have one that is a TextBox and the Name property is meBakBlauw?

Comment: @Mary I will check it

Comment: I edited the post with the full code, also I edited the small part because it gives the "Compile Error: Method or Datamember no found" prompt sooner on the same entry.

Comment: Apparently you had textboxes named `meBakBlauw` and `meBakGeel` on your form at some point. You don't have them anymore, all you have is an empty `Frame`.

Comment: @GSerg I updated my post with the .frm file, found out this hold some values

Comment: I don't know what `PVMaskEditLib` is. The only mention on the internet is in the context of malware. If this is something you developed in house, then apparently it used to have the Text property and now it does not.

Comment: PVMaskEditLib is is something delivered by a third party company (infragistics), licensed back then, the problem occures under 'Private Sub Form_Load()' where it highlights   "meBakBlauw.Text = "-" " and describing it as: " Compile Error:  Method or Datamember is not found. "

Comment: Both controls are marked as ReadOnly, try changing that in Properties Window (press F4 after you select meBakBlauw or meBakGeel control).

Comment: @Smith changed it, did not do anything unfortunatly, I am still getting the same Compile Error.

Comment: In Form_Load method try with Debug.Print meBakBlauw.Text instead of meBakBlauw.Text = "-" just to check if any use of Text property raises an error.

Comment: Please change "Visual Basic 2006" to "Visual Basic 6" in your question.

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville Changed it, thank you for the feedback!

Comment: @Smith still raises the same compile error, I updated my post with the most recent version I found on the programmer's computer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every **single** control on that form is a `PictureBox`. That normally happens if upon loading a project, VB can't resolve the (COM) references in the project file (*.vbp). In such cases, VB throws an error message upon startup and replaces any control with a PictureBox as a placeholder.

It should have also created a file called `frmKoppelBak.log` in the folder where the form resides, providing more information.

And I hope you haven't saved the changes of that form *(or have backups)*, otherwise you're stuck with th PictureBoxes. This *might* have happened, because you started VB6 under a normal user account on an OS > XP. Try launching the VB IDE *'As Administrator'*

Comment: I will have a look at the original file tomorrow, to see if certain controllers are replaced, thank you for the tip! Will follow up tomorrow